# ElasticSearch: Find mutual match in a document

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a simple document in ElasticSearch which denotes a 'like'

```
{
    "actorUserProfileId": Int,
    "userProfileId": Int
}
```

i.e actorUserProfileId is the profile Id of the actor profile & user profile Id is the profile Id of the target profile. I want to list all profiles where there is a mutual like.

`if y is the actorUserProfileId` then

```
    actorUserProfileId: x
    userProfileId: y

    actorUserProfileId: y
    userProfileId: x
```

Here `userProfileId = x` is the mutual match. I tried the script in ES but that didn't work i.e

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": {
                "script": {
                    "script": {
                        "source": "doc['actorUserProfileId'].value == doc['userProfileId'].value",
                        "lang": "painless"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My question is if the result can be achieved by directly querying the es without a server. With a server, I can create a result of ids from the first query and query the elastic for exact matches.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's not possible to achieve this in ES. I've switched to application-level joins to achieve this. Since the primary source of data, in this case, is RDBMS. It's easily possible to achieve this in RDBMS. For scale, I am considering building a OLAP pipeline on top of MySQL queries.